# Asking the date vs. the day of the week in German

Tags: usage, time, question

In English, if you ask someone "what date is it?" or "what's the date?", you'll get an answer like "the 20th of September". If you ask "what *day* is it?", you'll get an answer like "Monday", "Tuesday", etc..

How do you make this distinction in German? If I asked *welcher Tag ist Heute*, would it be understood as "what **date** is it?" or "what **day** is it?"

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, the most usual ways to ask for either the day of the week or the date are:

> Welchen Tag haben wir heute?
>
> Welchen Wochentag haben wir heute?

Answer would be: Monday! - The second question is completely unambigous.

> Welches Datum haben wir heute?
>
> Was für ein Datum haben wir heute?

Answer would be: Achtzehnter Oktober! - The second question could be considered slightly awkward (in the direction of wrong), but it will be met in the wild anyway.

Comment: Ich stimme zu, würde aber noch das umganggsprachlich häufig genutzte "Den wievielten haben wir heute?" / "Der wievielte ist heute?" hinzufügen. Sollte man in der Schriftsprache aber vermeiden.

Comment: Stimmt! "Der wievielte ist heute?" ist sehr häufig.

Comment: Mache bitte deutlicher, dass `Welchen Tag haben wir heute?` oder ähnliche Fragen tatsächlich zweideutig sind, weil vollkommen unklar ist (ohne Kontext) ob nach Datum oder Wochentag gefragt ist.

Comment: @Toscho "welchen Tag haben wir heute" ist (jedenfalls für mein norddeutsches Ohr) definitiv eindeutig, Das Wort (Wochen-)"Tag" kommt doch im Satz schon vor! Warum soll das zweideutig sein?

Comment: Ob nun der Tag der Woche oder der Tag des Monats, es geht in beiden Fällen um Tage. Das Datum ist eine eindeutige Angabe des Tages im Jahr. Also : welchen Wochentag haben wir heute oder welches Datum haben wir heute? Eine präzise Antwort auf welchen Tag haben wir heute wäre Montag der 25. September.

Comment: @Tommylee2k Nein, 'Wochentag' kommt in 'Welchen Tag haben wir heute?' eben nicht vor. Es könnte somit auch der Tag im Monat (ziemlich selten) oder der Tag im Jahr (häufig) sein, der gemeint ist.

Comment: @Toscho Ich denke doch, daß "WochenTAG" und "Tag" deutlich mehr gemeinhaben als "Tag" und "Datum". Ich hab "welchen Tag im Monat haben wir" noch nie gehört. So redet niemand. Und nur weil "ziemlich selten" jemand einen Ausdruck benutzen könnte ist der andere, sehr wohl allgemein gebräuchliche, nicht zweideutig.

Comment: @Tommylee2k Bei *häufig* statt *ziemlich selten* sieht es aber anders aus.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current day of week

> - Welcher Tag ist [denn] heute?
> - Was ist denn heute für ein Tag?

are often used, whereas

> Den wievielten haben wir denn heute?

is used to get the current date.

Comment: The first two sentences do *not* differentiate between weekday and date in German.

Comment: @Toscho: Wird _»Tag«_ gesagt, versteht der Hörer das gemeinhin als Wochentag, da sonst _»Datum«_ gesagt würde bzw. _»den wievielten / der wievielte«_.

Comment: *Gemeinhin* ist ein in Zusammenhang mit Missverständnissen sehr gefährliches Wort, und darum geht es ja hier.

Answer (score -1):

- Welches Datum haben wir (heute)?
- Was ist das aktuelle Datum?
- Welchen Kalendertag haben wir (heute)?

Comment: All of these describe asking for the date but there is no alternative for explicetly asking for the weekday.